# Subject-operator inversion

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, syntax, subject-auxiliary-inversion, negative-inversion

If a sentence begins with a negative or semi-negative word / phrase, it causes **subject-operator inversion** :

> "In no other way can the matter be explained."
>
> "Hardly had I seen Sam when he started walking."

Such inversion isn't found in the following sentence :

> "In no time we cleared the table." (*NOT, In no time did we clear the table.*)

Could you please clarify it?

Comment: Would you mind telling us what the sources are for these sentences? For example, I've heard, read and used variations of "we cleared the table in no time/in record time", but the form starting with "in no time" sounds a bit unusual to my ears, so I wonder where you came across it.

Comment: Perhaps relevant, [in no time](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/in-no-time-at-all) is an expression that means "very quickly", rather than a "negation" of time. Your first example sentence is different, because it does negate the possibility of other ways to explain the matter - you could rephrase it as "There is no other way in which the matter can be explained".

Comment: The first two sentences sound incredibly unnatural and awkward to me, and I don't think I've ever seen people use that type of sentence construction. There aren't technically incorrect, but they aren't typical

Answer (score 2):

There is an [article](https://awelu.srv.lu.se/grammar-and-words/selective-mini-grammar/subjects-and-predicate-verbs/the-order-of-subjects-and-verbs/) from Lund University in Sweden that explains:

> The inverted order only occurs when the whole clause is affected by the initial negation/restriction. Thus, there are cases where what appears to be an initial negative element does not trigger inverted word order.
>
> > In no time at all, the two doctors had more patients than they could handle.
>
> Here, the meaning of the sentence is affirmative rather than negative and therefore the clause retains its normal S-V order.

Your example sentence is also an affirmative one (the table *was* cleared). As I pointed out in my comment to your question, "in no time" is actually an expression that means "very quickly", so the sentence can be rephrased as:

> We cleared the table **very quickly**.

You can see more examples of where inversion is blocked even in the presence of negative constructions in the Wikipedia article on [negative inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_inversion).